# Function into a Python class

Tags: python, class, function, python-3.x

I am new in Python and I wrote the following code:

```
class Frazione:
    def __init__(self, Numeratore, Denominatore=1):
        mcd=MCD(Numeratore,Denominatore)
        self.Numeratore=Numeratore/mcd
        self.Denominatore=Denominatore/mcd

    def MCD(m,n):
        if m%n==0:
            return n
        else:
            return MCD(n,m%n)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%d/%d" %(self.Numeratore, self.Denominatore)

    def __mul__(self, AltraFrazione):
        if type(AltraFrazione)==type(5):
            AltraFrazione=Frazione(AltraFrazione)
        return Frazione(self.Numeratore*AltraFrazione.Numeratore, self.Denominatore*AltraFrazione.Denominatore)

    __rmul__=__mul__
```

Open shell at the same folder of Frazione.py:

```
>>> from Frazione import Frazione
```

end then

```
>>> f=Frazione(10,5)
```

When I press Enter, I receive this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\Frazione.py", line 5, in __init__
  mcd=MCD(Numeratore,Denominatore)
  NameError: global name 'MCD' is not defined
```

PS. I apologize for my english!

Comment: Note that it is recommended that you write your code with English identifiers. This makes getting help easier, and allows more people to read your code more easily. (Reference: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.)

Comment: Are you looking for [`fractions.Fraction`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) that comes with python?

Comment: I'm sorry for identifiers! I just copy and paste my code. Regarding the problem it was an exercise, so I don't care about `fractions.Fraction`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MCD` is a method of `Frazione`, but you're calling it as if it were a global function. The easiest (and cleanest, IMHO) fix is to just move it outside the class, because it doesn't need to access any class or instance members.

So:

```
def MCD(m, n):
    if m % n == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return MCD(n, m % n)

class Frazione:
    # as before but without MCD
```

If you do want to keep it in the class, then you might rewrite it to be iterative instead of recursive and call it as `self.MCD` in `__init__`. That's a good idea anyway, as Python's support for recursion is rather weak.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Python's support for recursion is rather weak"? Are you referring to the fact that function calls are relatively slow in Python?

Comment: @EOL: there is no tail call elimination, and [the BFDL doesn't want it either](http://neopythonic.blogspot.nl/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html). Then there's the speed issue, the single global depth limit (which can be reset, of course) and the fact that exception tracebacks can grow very large when using deep recursion, making debugging hard. The "flat is better than nested" maxim applies to algorithms as well as data structures.

Comment: If I move MCD outside the class it works. Thanks! But I don't know why, when I tried before to post this question, it didn't work. (: